# how to convert string into date format in iOS?

Tags: ios

I have string from web service like `12/31/2013 09:12:15 A.M`.
Now I Want convert it like `12 Dec 2013 09:12:15 A.M`.
with the use of `NSDAteFormatter` in iOS

Comment: Have you tried something? there are many question related to it.

Answer (score 6):

I'm giving you the answer, but downvoting your question for being too elementary and whose solution could easily found with a simple search.

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"];
NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:myDateString];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"dd MMMM yyyy aa:mm:ss a"];
NSString *newDate = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
```

Comment: To be exact: The date format should be @"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss a" because of AM/PM ;)

Comment: And if it's a 12-h format then the actual date format should be *@"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"*. Note the 'h' here. 'H' is for 24-h format.

Comment: You will need to include the `NSLocale` to make sure that the `AM/PM` is parsed correctly. Since not ever language/locale will use `A.M/P.M`.

Comment: The question expects an answer without shift in locale. The input and output should match.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *dateStr = @"12/31/2013 09:12:15 AM";

// Convert string to date object
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateStr];  

// Convert date object to desired output format
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"EEEE MMMM d, YYYY"];
dateStr = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];  
[dateFormat release];
```

Comment: You could at least try to match the date format in the question.