# How to convert a string Date & Time to NSDate in iOS?

Tags: ios, datepicker, uilocalnotification

I am facing a issue from last 2 days. My requirement is like this.

I have a start date as string. Like : **start_Date == 15-07-15**

And end date as string. Like : **end_Date == 16-07-15**

And time also like: **Start Time == 16:28, End Time == 18:28**

I combine 2 string and convert it into `NSDate`.

```
   NSString *strt_Date = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",start_Date, start_Time];
   NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
  [dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]];
  [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yy HH:mm"];
   NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:strt_Date];
```

Output is like this :

```
 date == 2015-07-15 11:01:00 +0000
```

Then I fire the notification :

```
[self scheduleNotificationForDate:date];

- (void)scheduleNotificationForDate:(NSDate *)date
{
  // Here we cancel all previously scheduled notifications
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];

  NSLog(@"date == %@",date);

  UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
  if (localNotif == nil)
      return;
  localNotif.fireDate = date;// this sets when notification will be called.
  // Notification details
  localNotif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
  localNotif.alertBody = @"Time to read your course";// this shows the alert box with message.
  // Set the action button

  localNotif.alertAction = @"View";
  localNotif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
  localNotif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = -1;

  // Schedule the notification
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];
}
```

*Note: My device also in 24 HR Format and this Date format also 24 Hr Format.*

My question is notification is not firing. Please Help me.

Comment: There are tons o questions about those 2 topics( for instance http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20949897/how-to-convert-string-into-date-format-in-ios ) , you should use NSDateFormatter https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/

Comment: Your date format is "dd-MM-yy HH:mm", then why you have the output as "2015-07-15 11:01:00 +0000"

Comment: Ya its coming like this. :)

Comment: If you are getting any permission error in the console, you have to add the following code also. if ([UIApplication instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert|UIUserNotificationTypeSound|UIUserNotificationTypeBadge
                                                                                                              categories:nil]];
    }

Comment: I already did it. Notification is not firing ..

Comment: Pls try my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

1 How to convert this string to NSDate & time ?

```
NSString *dateString = @"01-02-2010";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
// this is imporant - we set our input date format to match our input string
// if format doesn't match you'll get nil from your string, so be careful
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
NSDate *dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init];
// voila!
dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
```

2 How to set UILocalNotification using this date and time.

```
UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
localNotif.fireDate = selectedDate;
localNotif.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Notification for time : %@",newDate];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];
```

Here 'selectedDate' is an NSDate. You can follow the answer to the 1st question for converting your string date to NSDate.

Example with your function.

```
NSString *dateString = @"2015-07-15 12:19";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm"];
NSDate *dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init];
dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
[self scheduleNotificationForDate:dateFromString];
```

I just tried this code now and I got the notification.

Comment: No man, this is not showing proper date. How to combine my 2 date and time and schedule notification?

Comment: @SRNayak : You have to set the date format as per your requirement.

Comment: Yeah, I already done, but notification is not firing. I think date format is wrong. Tell me one thing, Notification will take only 12 hrs format ya 24 hrs format also?

Comment: If your device format is in 24 hrs, you have to set the fire date in 24 hr format. Otherwise you can use 12 hr format.

Comment: if i make it 12 hrs tehn it will fire immediately. Not waiting for scheduled time..

Comment: Can you please check the fire datetime and your device datetime.

Comment: I'm also updating my answer, I have used the same function that you have used to fire the notification.

Comment: pls comment "localNotif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];" this line in your function and try it once again.

Answer (score 0):

first create single string from date & time.

```
NSString *strt_Date = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",start_date,start_time];
NSString *endd_Date = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",end_date,end_time];
```

Than pass this string to following function

```
-(NSDate*)dateFromString:(NSString*)strDate
{
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"dd-MM-yy HH:mm";

    return [dateFormatter dateFromString:strDate];
}
```

then just set it to fireDate

Answer (score -1):

to get Date from string use NSDateFormatter ... like

```
NSDateFormatter *formater = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSLocale *usLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];
[formater setLocale:usLocale];
formater.dateStyle = NSDateIntervalFormatterFullStyle;
formater.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd";

NSDate *yourDate = [formater dateFromString:@"Your string"];
```